# Playframework non-static method <T>form(java.lang.Class<T>) cannot be referenced from a static context Error with Form

Tags: java, playframework

When I try to use below statement in my Playframework (2.5.4) applicaiton

```
Form<User> userForm = FormFactory.form(User.class);
```

It is giving me below error when I compile 
non-static method form(java.lang.Class) cannot be referenced from a static context, I understand I am calling non static class FormFactory, but its how the play framework website suggests, please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

its documentation is a little confusing what worked for me after read many forums was remove the static attribute that they suggest and the code ended up in this way

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.data.FormFactory;

public class Home extends Controller {
@Inject
FormFactory formFactory;

public Result processForm(){
    formFactory.form(log.class).bindFromRequest();
    return ok();
}

public class log {
    protected String logfile;

    public void setLog(String logfile) {
        this.logfile = logfile;
    }

    public String getLog() {
        return logfile;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using play 2.5.5 by the way